# Sublime FTPS Can't Validate Folder

Tags: amazon-ec2, ftp, sublimetext3

**Issue:** When trying to connect to my server through Sublime SFTP Plugin using the supported FTPS method, everything seems to go smoothly except for the validation of the folder.

I have searched all over for a recourse to resolve this issue to no avail.

The strange part is when I look at my FileZilla Server Logs it seems to connect to the server just fine but the connection ends when it goes into PASV mode.

**Below are the logs from the server:**

> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:50 PM - (not logged in) (73.102.144.11)>
>   Connected on port 21, sending welcome message...
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:50 PM - (not logged in) (73.102.144.11)>
>   220-FileZilla Server 0.9.60 beta
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:50 PM - (not logged in) (73.102.144.11)> 220
>   Welcome to the Collab Server
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:50 PM - (not logged in) (73.102.144.11)> AUTH
>   TLS
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:50 PM - (not logged in) (73.102.144.11)> 234
>   Using authentication type TLS
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:50 PM - (not logged in) (73.102.144.11)> TLS
>   connection established
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:51 PM - (not logged in) (73.102.144.11)> USER
>   msechrest
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:51 PM - (not logged in) (73.102.144.11)> 331
>   Password required for msechrest
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:51 PM - (not logged in) (73.102.144.11)> PASS
>
> ---
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:51 PM - msechrest (73.102.144.11)> 230 Logged
>   on
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:51 PM - msechrest (73.102.144.11)> PBSZ 0
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:51 PM - msechrest (73.102.144.11)> 200 PBSZ=0
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:51 PM - msechrest (73.102.144.11)> PROT P
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:51 PM - msechrest (73.102.144.11)> 200
>   Protection level set to P
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:52 PM - msechrest (73.102.144.11)> PWD
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:52 PM - msechrest (73.102.144.11)> 257 "/" is
>   current directory.
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:52 PM - msechrest (73.102.144.11)> CWD
>   /laravel/collabsession
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:52 PM - msechrest (73.102.144.11)> 250 CWD
>   successful. "/laravel/collabsession" is current directory.
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:52 PM - msechrest (73.102.144.11)> TYPE I
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:52 PM - msechrest (73.102.144.11)> 200 Type
>   set to I
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:52 PM - msechrest (73.102.144.11)> PASV
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:52 PM - msechrest (73.102.144.11)> 227
>   Entering Passive Mode (127,0,0,1,55,249)
>
> (000056)5/16/2017 21:15:53 PM - msechrest (73.102.144.11)>
>   disconnected.

**Additional Information**
I can connect to the server fine using FileZilla Client from another desktop.
The server is on a Windows 10 AWS and has an elastic IP address.
I have opened port 21 for both the inbound and outbound rules on the firewall as well as added the program FileZilla Server as an exception in the inbound rules.
I went onto the AWS Admin Panel and added all of the ports (21, 990, and 14200 - 14400) to my inbound rules. 14200 - 14400 are the passive mode port ranges I specified on the FileZilla Server Admin Panel.

Could someone please point me in the right direction or let me know what I am doing wrong? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SFTP vs. FTPS](https://www.goanywhere.com/blog/2011/10/20/sftp-ftps-secure-ftp-transfers)

> In regards to how easy each of the secure FTP protocols are to
>   implement, SFTP is the clear winner since it is very firewall
>   friendly. SFTP only needs a single port number (default of 22) to be
>   opened through the firewall.  This port will be used for all SFTP
>   communications, including the initial authentication, any commands
>   issued, as well as any data transferred.
>
> On the other hand, FTPS can be very difficult to patch through a
>   tightly secured firewall since FTPS uses multiple port numbers. The
>   initial port number (default of 21) is used for authentication and
>   passing any commands.  However, every time a file transfer request
>   (get, put) or directory listing request is made, another port number
>   needs to be opened.  You and your trading partners will therefore have
>   to open a range of ports in your firewalls to allow for FTPS
>   connections, which can be a security risk for your network.

If you are using FTPS, you will face this issue based on the comments above.

**The initial port number (default of 21) is used for authentication and passing any commands. However, every time a file transfer request (get, put) or directory listing request is made, another port number needs to be opened.**

The most secure option is to use SFTP instead of FTPS.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. I will wait to see if anyone else has another suggestion, but in the mean time I will research how to SFTP into a windows machine. I originally was under the impression that SFTP was only used to SSH into a Linux machine.

Comment: @Matthew a quick google leads to this link: https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server

Comment: That's for FTPS. For SFTP, see https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_openssh_server

Comment: @YeshodhanKulkarni Thank you for those resources. After looking at them, they seemed to make things more complicated by not including everything needed in one resource (instead they link out to other resources) which made it difficult to follow along. Instead I used https://youtu.be/CXzBdVXjKGU as my resource and I have gotten everything working properly using SFTP instead of FTPS. Thank you for leading me in the right direction! Cheers!